# Qt : KeyPress event

Tags: c++, qt

i am starter in Qt and was implementing keypressevent.
I want to handle keys in such a way that if 'A' is pressed it shoud print 'R' and press of other key i should print.

How this type of activity can be handled in Qt...??

Comment: What did you tried? Did you read the Qt documentation?

Answer (score 19):

You can get the key that was pressed by using a `key()` function. The list of codes for the keys can be found [at this doc page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#Key-enum). So, if you want your `A` key, you can either do

```
keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent * event )
{
    if( event->key() == Qt::Key_A )
    {
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

or use the key code directly:

```
if( event->key() == 0x41 )
{
    // do your stuff here
}
```